# How can I add information to a C# oData result set after the filters have been applied

Tags: c#, performance, linq, odata

I am using c# MVC and have an oData-powered view to display data from a large table (~1 million rows). Much of the data can be queried and displayed straight from the database, but one column needs to be reformatted to include data looked up from another database.

It would be too slow to run these lookups across all 1 million rows in the database, but it would be fine to run them against the 20 rows that are being returned to the user. I do not need to sort or filter on these columns.

How can I run these lookups after the rows have already been filtered?

One potential pattern could be:

```
public class LogController : System.Web.Http.OData.OdataController
{
        public IQueryable<LogResult> GetLogs(ODataQueryOptions opts)
        {
            ODataV2(Request);

            var logs = LogRepository.All();

            /* Do something here to filter out unwanted results */

            // I'll need to convert to a list if I'm going to run a foreach over it
            var logsList = logs.ToList()

            foreach (var log in logsList)
            {
                log.CalculatedProperty = ExpensiveFunction(log);
            }
            return logsList.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively maybe there is a way to post-process the output of GetLogs before it is returned to the user? Or I can use a calculated property of Log?

The key thing is I want to run ExpensiveFunction() 20 times, instead of 1 million.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some little trick to prevent converting to list and vise versa:

```
/* Do something here to filter out unwanted results */

return logs.Select(l => {
    l.CalculatedProperty = ExpensiveFunction(log);

    return l; // or even yield return
});
```

I can't say that this solution is the best, but in some cases it might be a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply the QueryOption and then update the result?

Change return type to `IHttpActionResult`

```
var logsList = ops.ApplyTo(logs, new ODataQuerySettings()).toList();
// reform logsList
return MakeGenericResult(logsList.AsQueryable(), logsList.AsQueryable().GetType());

private IHttpActionResult Ok(object content, Type type)
{
    var resultType = typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(resultType, content, this) as IHttpActionResult;
}
```